# Get time signatures to show up in a ChordNames context

Tags: lilypond

I'm working off the "[adding bar lines to chord names context](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/snippets/chords)" example, but have variable time signatures in my piece.  I'd like those to show up as numeric time signatures in the same line as the chord names.  How can I get the time signature to show up?

This minimal example:

```
<pre> 
\version "2.18.2"


\new ChordNames \with {
   \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-2 . 2)
   \consists "Bar_engraver"
}

\chordmode {
   \time 4/4 f1:maj7 
   \time 2/4 f2:7 
   \time 4/4 bes1:7
}
</pre>
```

gets the bar lines in the right places but does not display the time signature in any form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the time signature engraver using `\consists`, and (optionally) set the context to use numeric time signatures:

```
    \version "2.18.2"

    \new ChordNames \with {
        \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-2 . 2)
        \consists "Bar_engraver"
        \consists "Time_signature_engraver"
        \numericTimeSignature
    }
```